# IIS URL rewrite rule(Pattern) doe not recognize {HTTP_HOST} when request is made from HTTPS protocol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have domain E.g.
'example.com'
I want to redirect all traffic to 'https://www.example.com' (as I have certificate that is only valid for 'www.example.com')
when I type 'http://example.com' it worked fine and redirect me to 'https://www.example.com' as expected

**Issue:** When I make request with 'https://example.com' it does not redirected by rule to 'https://www.example.com'. Not sure why its failing with https?

**Here is rule detail that i have applied.**

```
<rule name="example.com to https://www.example.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
     </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
           <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: i have to redirect 'example.com' to 'www.example.com' with https. in this case if i will make request with 'http://example.com it will open 'https ://example.com' which will give me certificate error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule

Comment: 'http ://example.com' 
{HTTP_HOST} = example.com,
or
'http ://www.example.com'
{HTTP_HOST} = www.example.com @ajinkya